# Try and Except - Understanding how it is used in finding data specific to dates

Tags: python

I have been trying to understand a piece of code that includes Try and Except that filters data based on specific/required dates:

```
required_date = '2021-02-11'

index_for_date = (data_dict['date'] == required_date)
data_filtered_by_date = {}
for key in data_dict.keys():
    try:
        data_filtered_by_date[key] = np.float_(data_dict[key][index_for_date])
    except:
        data_filtered_by_date[key] = data_dict[key][index_for_date]
```

I do not understand why the Try and Except would be used and how the whole code would function. I have researched specifics such as `np.float` and why we use two crotchets (e.g. `[key][index_for_date]`, why are they together?) next to each other. Hopefully I can get further clarification on this code as I am very new to Python and have done various forms of research in order to find some sort of answer

Comment: So, what did you find out about `np.float_()`?

Comment: Unfortunately very little, which is why I am very confused

Comment: I recommend you to read the tutorial of exception handling in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html After reading it, your answer may answer itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with an explanation of your code. `data_dict` is a dictionary of data columns, one of which is the `'date'` column on which you want to filter. `index_for_date = (data_dict['date'] == required_date)` constructs a Boolean index for the columns to find the specific data (an array which is all false except where it matches the desired date).

You loop over the columns which are in `data_dict[key]`. Then for each column, you select the ones matching the date using the Boolean index: `data_dict[key][index_for_date]` that is why you have two sets of square brackets, this first is dict indexing, the second is Boolean array indexing.

Then in the `try` clause, you try to cast the values to floats using `np.float_`. If this fails (it throws an exception), you fall back to the 'raw', non casted values.

Comment: Great answer, it really helped me understand. But why would It use np.float_ for the try and except?

Comment: Well, I think you need to know the context of this code to really understand why it would do that. If the data can be originating from a text file and exist in the columns as strings for example and the code later will be handling the data as if it were floats, this step makes sense. This step is not really part of the filtering itself but rather data parsing. BTW, if this answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted.